# Halacha series publications

Tags: halacha, publications

Anyone know of a Halacha mailing besides the RJJ Halacha publication? Weekly would be best, but monthly or quarterly works as well. It can be any area of Halacha, but should be by an esteemed posek/poskim.

Comment: You asked http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73379, and it was closed as too broad. The solution isn't to delete it and re-ask the same thing. The solution is to narrow the question so it can be reopened to answers. What exactly are you looking for? Obviously, per your comment here, something "more to the 'right'" than Loewian's two suggestions. Great! Then [edit] that criterion into your question so answerers can tailor their answers to your needs. Also edit in any other criteria you have, or other information on your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The [Techumin](http://www.rambish.org.il/results.asp?SearchFunction=browse&SearchCode=BRW_INJ&SearchRequest=70) series is an excellent annual compilation of in-depth halachic discourses (in hebrew) on current issues by prominent Rabbis of the times.

There are generally around 30 - 60 essays in each volume that address many topics (different in each volume), for example: shabbat & yom tov, medical ethics, economics & finances, politics and law, community related issues, conversion, science, mitzvot, the army, family purity, issur v'heter, current issues, and more.

Answer (score 1):

You also might like this. The *Dirshu* Orginization puts out a monthly bulletin on the halachos they learnt over the course of the month. I can say from experience that they are very enjoyable and interesting!

[An example of the Bulletin is on this site](http://www.dafhalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/DHYB-Monthly-Bulletin-Elul-English-FOR-PRINT-09-02-15.pdf)